# Using Checkboxes or a Checkboxlist to populate a textbox and dynamically knowing when to add and/or?

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I am trying to incorporate a series of checkboxes and based on what is checked it will populate a textbox.

Region: AMER, APAC, EMEA

Status: Active, Retired, Pre-Go-Live

I have it working with one checkbox where it will add the text in, but I am trying to figure out how to make is know when it needs to add and and/or.

```
    Protected Sub chkbxRegionAMER_CheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkbxRegionAMER.CheckedChanged
    If chkbxRegionAMER.Checked = True Then
        txtSearch.Text &= "Region=""AMER"""
    ElseIf chkbxRegionAMER.Checked = False Then
        txtSearch.Text = txtSearch.Text.Replace("Region=""AMER""", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

This inputs "Region="AMER"" into the textbox like I expected. However, if I added the other checkboxes I wouldn't know how to make it say "Region="AMER" or Region="APAC" and status="active"" regardless of the order. If all checkboxes were selected it could end up looking like this: (Region="AMER" or Region="EMEA" or Region="APAC") and (status="Retired" or Status="Active" or status="Pre-Go-Live")

I assume using a checkbox list would be the best way to do this, but I have no idea how to use those. Maybe there is a better way to do this entirely. I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would create a new sub `BuildText` then count how many checkboxes are checked, then use a [StringBuilder](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-vbnet) to create your textbox text.

Comment: Is this a WinForms or Web Forms project?  You should add ALL the appropriate tags.

Comment: @DaveB Can you give me an example of how that would be done?

Comment: @jmcilhinney It is a Web Forms project. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that, if you're creating a VB.NET Web Forms project then you should tag with Web Forms as well as VB.NET, which I have now done for you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh, my apologies. I thought you meant tags within the project and was confused. You are right, I should have added that as a tag. I appreciate you doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below in C#

Use below functions Add and Remove when its checked and unchecked

```
  txtSearch.Text = AddText(txtSearch.Text, "Region=\"AMER\"");
   txtSearch.Text = RemoveText(txtSearch.Text, "Region=\"AMER\"");


private string AddText(string strOriginalString, string strTextToAdd)
        {
            //check if string is already there or not
            if (!strOriginalString.ToLower().Contains(strTextToAdd.ToLower()))
            {
                strOriginalString += strTextToAdd;
            }
            return strOriginalString;
        }
        private string RemoveText(string strOriginalString, string strTextToRemove)
        {
            //replace string with blank
            strOriginalString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strOriginalString, strTextToRemove, string.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return strOriginalString;
        }
```

COnverted VB.Net functions:

```
txtSearch.Text = AddText(txtSearch.Text, "Region=""AMER""")
txtSearch.Text = RemoveText(txtSearch.Text, "Region=""AMER""")

Private Function AddText(strOriginalString As String, strTextToAdd As String) As String
    'check if string is already there or not
    If Not strOriginalString.ToLower().Contains(strTextToAdd.ToLower()) Then
        strOriginalString += strTextToAdd
    End If
    Return strOriginalString
End Function
Private Function RemoveText(strOriginalString As String, strTextToRemove As String) As String
    'replace string with blank
    strOriginalString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strOriginalString, strTextToRemove, String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Return strOriginalString
End Function
```

Updated Code:

```
  private string AddText(string strOriginalString, string strTextToAdd, bool bIsRegion)
    {
        //check if string is already there or not
        if (!strOriginalString.ToLower().Contains(strTextToAdd.ToLower()))
        {
            string strFirstPart = string.Empty;
            string strSecondPart = string.Empty;

            string[] twoParts = strOriginalString.Split(new[] { ") AND (" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            strFirstPart = twoParts[0];
            if (twoParts.Length > 1)
            {
                strSecondPart = twoParts[1];
            }


            if (bIsRegion)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFirstPart))
                {
                    //add or condition for added text
                    strFirstPart += " OR " + strTextToAdd;
                }
                else
                {
                    strFirstPart += strTextToAdd;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //for status add

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSecondPart))
                {
                    //add or condition for added text
                    strSecondPart += " OR " + strSecondPart;
                }
                else
                {
                    strSecondPart += strTextToAdd;
                }

            }
            strOriginalString = GetFullString(strFirstPart, strSecondPart);
        }
        return strOriginalString;
    }
    private string RemoveText(string strOriginalString, string strTextToRemove, bool bIsRegion)
    {
        //if contain then remove
        if (strOriginalString.ToLower().Contains(strTextToRemove.ToLower()))
        {
            //replace string with blank
            strOriginalString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strOriginalString, strTextToRemove, string.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return strOriginalString;

            string strFirstPart = string.Empty;
            string strSecondPart = string.Empty;

            string[] twoParts = strOriginalString.Split(new[] { ") AND (" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            strFirstPart = twoParts[0];
            if (twoParts.Length > 1)
            {
                strSecondPart = twoParts[1];
            }


            if (bIsRegion)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFirstPart))
                {
                    //remove from fist conditon
                    strFirstPart = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strFirstPart, strTextToRemove, string.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    strFirstPart = String.Join("-", strFirstPart.Split(new string[] { " OR " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSecondPart))
                {
                    //remove from fist conditon
                    strSecondPart = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strSecondPart, strTextToRemove, string.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    strSecondPart = String.Join("-", strSecondPart.Split(new string[] { " OR " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                }


            }
            strOriginalString = GetFullString(strFirstPart, strSecondPart);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    string GetFullString(string strFirstPart, string strSecondPart)
    {

        strFirstPart = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strFirstPart) ? "(" + strFirstPart + ")" : string.Empty;
        strSecondPart = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSecondPart) ? "(" + strSecondPart + ")" : string.Empty;

        strFirstPart = strFirstPart.Replace("((", string.Empty);
        strSecondPart = strSecondPart.Replace("((", string.Empty);
        strFirstPart = strFirstPart.Replace("))", string.Empty);
        strSecondPart = strSecondPart.Replace("))", string.Empty);

        return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSecondPart) ? strFirstPart + " AND " + strSecondPart : strFirstPart);
    }
```

Comment: This is nice, but it  essentially does the same thing I was already doing. My main issue is how to handle when adding additional search criteria and how to know when to add an "and" or an "or" and appropriate parentheses. 

i.e. (region="AMER" or region="EMEA") and (status="active" or status="retried")

Comment: I have updated the  answer you will get idea for this there might be some issues with bracket but i have provided the approach for this in code with comments

Comment: I'll try to convert this to vb and give it a go